# Счетчик цифр с двумя интервалами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна ваша помощь в js и jquery.
Суть задачи такая - есть определенное число, например 190 000 тонн, при загрузке страницы это число должно с 0 досчитать до 190 000 за 15 секунд, а после этого каждые 30 секунд прибавлять еще по 1 (т.е. 190 001, 190 002 и т.д.).
Сохранять в кэше не нужно.

```
<span class="counter-number">192000</span> тонн произведено.
```

Первую часть скрипта я попытался наколхозить, а как потом после выполнения этой части, начать прибавлять по 1, я не оч понимаю.

```
$('.counter-number').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 8000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал не на задержках а при помощи дельты времени между кадрами:

```js
let d = 190000;
let t1 = 1000;
let t2 = 3000;

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(dt) {
  let amount = dt < t1 ? dt*d/t1 : (dt-t1)/t2 + d - 1;
  document.querySelector('div').textContent =  Math.ceil(amount);
  document.querySelector('span').textContent = (dt/1000).toFixed(2) + " sec";
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

тут стоит `t1` = 1 секунда на первый интервал и `t2` = 3 секунды на второй (чтобы не ждать)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вполне себе рабочее решение. Единственный момент: чтобы досчитать до 190 000 за 15 секунд, надо считать очень быстро, поэтому я сделал счёт сотнями. Ну и второй интервал для наглядности сделал 3 секунды, а не 30.

В принципе с параметром delay и инкрементом currentIndex Вы можете поиграться сами и посмотреть, как лучше для Вашей задачи. Главное, потестируйте в разных браузерах, потому что не все движки могут корректно отрабатывать при счёте единицами в короткий промежуток времени.

```js
const counter = function(elem, delay, num) {
  for(let currentIndex=0; currentIndex<=num; currentIndex+=100) {
    (function(index) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.textContent = index;
        if(index == num) {
          num++;
          setInterval(function(){
            elem.textContent = num;
            num++;
          }, 3000)
        }
      }, delay*index);
    })(currentIndex);
  }
}
const counterNumber = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-number')[0];
counter(counterNumber, 0.08, 190000);
```

```html
<div><span class="counter-number"></span> тонн произведено</div>
```